# Array of unknown size to variables

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

I have an array as incoming parameter of my function, and I'd like to assign array elements to variables, like:

```
Dim Par1 As String = Array(0).ToString
Dim Par2 As String = Array(1).ToString
...
```

But there is a problem because this array of variable size (0-10) so it's impossible to assign variables in that hardcoded way. Is there an elegant way to dynamically assign elements to variables depending on array size ?

Update: so far I have this stupid code:

```
If Params.Length > 0 Then Dim Par1 As String = Array(0).ToString
If Params.Length > 1 Then Dim Par2 As String = Array(1).ToString
...
If Params.Length > 10 Then Dim Par11 As String = Array(10).ToString
```

let me know if there's some better way...
oops... seems like I have to declare variables explicitly first...

Comment: You can use the foreach loop to loop through your array of strings and do what ever you want with each item.

Comment: I am not sure what you trying to achieve here but you need to run loop and assign value

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want this? What are you going to do with `Par9`?

Comment: One way of *thinking* about an array is that it's already a collection of variables where the number that are being used is determined at runtime instead of compile time. Why can you not just keep using the array?

Comment: and how can I hardcode variable names in for each loop? their names must be declared dynamically depending on array size - par1, par2... etc. I cannot declare all 10 variables coz I may have "index out of bounds" error when assigning values

Comment: I will keep using an array if I cannot solve this... In fact, I have to do some tricks with Array(0...10) values, and if I keep using it my code will become hard to read

Comment: @ladybug: What you going to do with these variables 1,2,3 etc...??

Comment: We might have more useful suggestions to make if you could explain what *problem* you're trying to solve. It looks like you've broken your problem down into an impossible part and an easy part, and now you're asking us for help with the impossible part.

Comment: I just want to increase readability... I have to pass array elements as arguments to another functions, and instead of passing bla.Array(0).blabla I'd like to pass variables [variable=bla.Array(0).blabla]
So, in other words, how can I check if array(element) exists before assigning it to variable (in design-time)?

Comment: You should avoid having variable like Par1/Par2/PAr3/... arrays are there exactly for this purpose.

Comment: As others have stated, keeping the array and looping over it or accessing it's members by index is the way to go.  The only other way to do what you're asking is to declare a bunch of variables and start tossing the array items into them up until the ubound(array) or array.count.  That IMO would make you code harder to read because you would have to declare and then potentially use any number of array items so you would have to add code for all of those (as opposed to just say, a loop).

Comment: Also, side note, if you declare a variable in an If block then it will only be accessible in that If block.  You have to have it declared outside of it for the entire method to have access to it's scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to want to loop over your items if your goal is readability.  You would have to declare an unknown number of variables at design time which means you would have a lot of if checking and then putting into variables (and then you would probably have to declare a lot of variables you wouldn't use in some cases).  Also, you've doubled the amount of strings you have by duplicating them (I'm assuming they're strings).  Here's some looping examples.

I create a string array of variable size (like you said you would be getting passed in).  Then, I loop over each item and assign it a value I made up.  After I show a for each loop that will go through each item.

```
    ' Random number generator
    Dim rnd As New Random

    ' Declare a string array of variable size
    Dim variableArray(rnd.Next(10)) As String

    ' Loop by index, we'll just assign some text as an example
    For x As Integer = 0 To variableArray.Count - 1
        variableArray(x) = String.Format("Item {0}", x)
    Next

    ' Alternate way to loop over your array with a for each
    For Each item As String In variableArray
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...")
    Console.ReadKey()
```

That said, if you knew what variables were coming in and they had meaning you could assign them to properties in an object on a class you create (or to meaningful variable names).

Comment: >You would have to declare an unknown number of variables at design time which means you would have a lot of if checking and then putting into variables
----
Since I have to pass array elements into functions as arguments later, I should know exactly (and I do) how much array elements I receive at a time (it equals to number of function's arguments). You got the point - problem is to declare unknown number of variables at design time, depending on array size. Looks like I have to stay with modified in foreach loop array(elements)...